# Problems with line numbers being printed in Python (LPTHW Ex20)

Tags: python

Im new to Python and coding and I've been working my way through Learn Python The Hard Way and just finished ex20, I completed everything and pretty sure I understand it all but for some reason when I run the following script I dont get the numbers 1,2 and 3 at the start of the lines at the end, I dont get any errors though.

**This is my code:**

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline(),

current_file = open(input_file)

print "First let's print the whole file:\n"
print # a blank line

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line += 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line += 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

**and this is what you should see:**

```
$ python ex20.py test.txt
First let's print the whole file:

This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3

Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.
Let's print three lines:
1 This is line 1

2 This is line 2

3 This is line 3
```

**But this is what I get in Powershell**

```
PS C:\Users\David\lpthw> python ex20.py test.txt

First let's print the whole file:


 ■t h i s   i s   a   l i n e   1

 t h i s   i s   a   l i n e   2

 t h i s   i s   a   l i n e   3


Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.
Let's print three lines:

   ■t h i s   i s   a   l i n e   1

   t h i s   i s   a   l i n e   2

   t h i s   i s   a   l i n e   3
```

I've been over my code line by line and cant see why I dont get the numbers at the start of those last 3 lines nor why I have those blocks at the start

Comment: What happens if you put `print repr(f.read())` in the `print_all()` function? So instead of the `print f.read()` that is there now? Can you share the output of *just* that print statement?

Comment: `test.txt` is likely a UTF-16 file, rather than a regular plain text file.  That explains the strange formatting and the block at the start (a "BOM"), but not the missing numbers...

Answer (score 0):

If your using Notepad++, I was having the same problem. I tried switching over to notepad and almost had the problem fixed when I saved in UTF-8. Finally, I tried saving it in encoding ANSI and it came out perfect. For Notepad++, when you write your text files, just go to the top menu bar and ensure that ANSI is selected.